# List Attribute values selected by location

Tags: fme-form, select

I would like to get a list of road features that intersect every county in a state and output it as CSV or Excel. 
Ex: county A intersect the Road Names

- a
- b
- c

county B intersect the Road Names

- e
- f

Any ideas using FME?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Try looking into the lineOnarea transformer. Or the spatial filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just had another look at this one and what you want to do can be done with a single transformer: the **[LineOnArea Overlayer](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/FME_Transformers.htm#Transformers/lineonareaoverlayer.htm)**.

I've done a similar thing as a test.

[image]

In my example, the reader at the top is the roads, and the bottom reader is the local government areas (counties in your example).  Connect them appropriately, and connect the line output to the CSV Writer. You can keep or remove unwanted attributes with an **[AttributeKeeper](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/FME_Transformers.htm#Transformers/attributekeeper.htm)** or [**AttributeRemover**](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/FME_Transformers.htm#Transformers/attributeremover.htm%3FTocPath%3DFME%2520Transformers%7CAll%2520Workbench%2520Transformers%7C_____50).

You can also sort your data based on County Name using a **[Sorter](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/FME_Transformers.htm#Transformers/sorter.htm%3FTocPath%3DFME%2520Transformers%7CAll%2520Workbench%2520Transformers%7C_____382)**.

Your output should have Road Name in one column, and County Name in the other.

Comment: I followed your example and it gives me exactly what I expected: Road Name-County-Overlaps (1 or 0). What I started yesterday was to create a ModelBuilder (SelectByLocation-CopyFeatures), then Export it to Python and try to sort it by county, but with FME is much more easier :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to set junctions at the intersections and then join again where the valance nodes are exactly two. You can try using Intersector, LineJoiner, LineOnAreaOverlay,SpatialFilter in the specific sequence. You might have to use [AttributeExploder](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/FME_Transformers.htm#Transformers/attributeexploder.htm) and provide the value in expose elements.